# How can I solved this error in flutter class code

Tags: flutter, class, dart

I write this class

```
class Profile {
  String email;
  String password;

  Profile({this.email, this.password});
}
```

But it said that

```
"The parameter 'email' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.dartmissing_default_value_for_parameter"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding required:

```
class Profile {
  String email;
  String password;

  Profile({
    required this.email,
    required this.password,
  });
}
```

By adding optional:

```
class Profile {
  String? email;
  String? password;

  Profile({
    this.email,
    this.password,
  });
}
```

By adding default values:

```
class Profile {
  String email;
  String password;

  Profile({
    this.email = "mail@gmail.com",
    this.password = "123",
  });
}
```

Comment: @Phut what is wrong with my answer...i have added all the possible ways for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make them accept a `null` value.

```
class Profile {
  String? email;
  String? password;

  Profile({this.email, this.password});
}
```